# Splitting polygon into multiple equal-width polygons in ArcMap 10

Tags: arcmap, polygon, arcgis-10.0, splitting

I am adding parking spaces into a parking lot, and I need them to be exactly the same shape and not overlap each other or have spaces between. In ArcMap 9.3, there was an editing task that allowed you to split a long rectangle into multiple, equal-width polygons. I am having trouble finding this tool in ArcMap 10. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Do you have any solution for this problem? The parcel editor seems to address this issue perfect, but it is only available with the Editor and Info Version which cost a fortune. We are also trying to divide a lot of polygons on a regular basis - any help would be highly appreciated ...

Comment: I still don't have a solution for the problem. I swear there was something simple in 9.3, but I don't have access to it so I can't test it. I suppose this would likely be possible with a custom python add-in in ArcGIS 10.1.

Answer (score 8):

Have you looked at the fishnet tool?

I *assume* it also exists in arc 10 :)

Data management tools / feature class / create fishnet: it chops up an area into equal sized polygons...  I have used this for making grids.

Good luck!

Comment: Didn't realize fishnet had an "angle of rotation" parameter: http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/How_Create_Fishnet_Data_Management_works/001700000030000000/ Good suggestion.

Comment: Fishnet does exist in ArcGIS 10.

Comment: The Fishnet tool will not divide an arbitrary polygon. It just creates a matrix or grid with any number of rows/columns at a user defined angle. You can define the origin also.

Comment: @Tanner - the Create Fishnet (Data Management) tool is almost certainly what you need. For any  application where you're dicing a square or rectangular polygon into equal parts, Fishnet is the answer.  

Here's how I used it:  
1. Get the extents (top, bottom, left, right) of the polygon you wish to divide.   Jot these down.  
2. Enter the values from your coordinates of the rectangular polygon as the   Template Extent values

Comment: Addition to previous comment:  
3. Fill in only the Number of Rows and Number of Columns parameters.  
To split polygon into three parts, horizontally: Number of Rows = 1 and Number   of Columns = 3To split in five parts, vertically: Number of Rows = 5 and   Number of Columns = 1

Answer (score 8):

**The Parcel Editor Toolbar** offers this functionality, free with Arc 10. You need an Editor or ArcInfo license. Select a feature with the Select Parcel Feature tool, right-click Parcel Division. You can divide by Equal Area or Equal Width.

Please see the ESRI online help ([parcel division](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001t000003wp000000.htm)).

Answer (score 5):

**ArcGIS 10 Version**

Resource Center » Professional Library » Data Management » Editing data » Editing existing features

Cut Polygons tool  [image]

http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001t00000088000000.htm

Editing and data compilation > Editing existing features

**9.3 Version**
http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Splitting_polygon_features

Comment: I already knew about the cut tool. I'm looking for a tool that will automatically cut and divide a polygon evenly, given certain parameters such as Number of divisions or width of output polygons.

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head, I don't know of anything in 9.3 that does what you're describing. It does look like 10 has a tool to do this when you're working with parcel fabrics:  [Creating new parcels using divide by area](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Creating_new_parcels_using_divide_by_area/001t0000012s000000/).

Answer (score 1):

I think the fishnet tool is the best solution. The polygon to be split can be given as template. This will ensure that the resultant grid is within the required polygon boundary.
any suggestions ---

Answer (score 0):

Try Grid Index Features. It is under Cartography Tools/Data Driven Page/Grid Index Features.