# Divide a large polygon into 4 smaller ones having same area

Tags: arcgis-desktop, editing

Is there anyway to divide a large polygon into 4 smaller polygons having same area. for example, I have an area of 1 hectare but I would like to divide it into 4 plots having 2500 m2 for each. if anyone knows the solution, please help.

Comment: There are an infinite number of ways to accomplish this, but the problem itself is very difficult to solve for irregular shapes (computationally expensive).  That said, this question already has an answer http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3130/how-to-split-a-polygon-into-multiple-equal-width-polygons-in-arcmap-10