# Cut polygon into equal parts

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, arcgis-10.3

Is there a way to cut a polyon in equal parts?

Basically, I have several rectangles that I need to divide into equal parts, either 3, 4 or 5 equal parts.

I am using ArcGIS 10.3.1

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3130/how-to-split-a-polygon-into-multiple-equal-width-polygons-in-arcmap-10

Comment: I did see this, I was wondering if there was a script or something simple out there.

Comment: This http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/159631/splitting-all-polygon-features-in-a-shapefile-into-smaller-equal-width-polygons/159653#159653 will need a wee bit of tweaking

Comment: Any other criteria? Do you want a bearing line, minimum length splits, etc? There are a lot of solutions, just wondering if any would do or you want a more specific one.

Comment: Duplicate of: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5300/dividing-polygon-into-specific-sizes-using-arcgis-desktop/312144

Answer (score 2):

If you want to split Rectangle into equal parts, then you able to done it by the reference of line feature:

1. Draw a line on one side of rectangle. (Snap vertices of line to vertices of rectangle).
2. Select line.
3. Go to Editor
4. Select Split
5. Check into “In to equal parts” and write parts in textbox you want to split.
6. Click OK
7. Now select your rectangle.
8. And with the reference of end points of your broken parts of line, cut your rectangle.
   (**Note**: Take parallel your cutting line to opposite side of your rectangle).

Its done.

Answer (score 0):

I think this script would work for you: https://tereshenkov.wordpress.com/2017/09/10/dividing-a-polygon-into-a-given-number-of-equal-areas-with-arcpy/

The script asks for your polygon and how many sections you want it to divide into. Then you tell it either to make cuts N-S or W-E (unfortunately, you won’t be able to specify the angle yourself) and it will divide the polygon up that way.

[image: The illustration of the polygon subdivision (West-East to the left, North-South to the right).]

The script write broke it down this way:

1.Get an extent of a polygon.
2. Construct a polyline using the vertices of the polygon’s extent with
    a tiny shift of coordinates.
3. Cut the polygon into two halves using this line.
4.Find what is the area of the smallest polygon.
5.If the area is smaller than the 200 sq. m. (that is, fifth part of
    the polygon), the shift the line again and re-run steps 2-4. 
6. If the area is 200 sq. m. or larger, than leave this part and keep
    working with the polygon that is left essentially running through
    the steps 2-5.
7. When the original polygon has been successfully divided into equal
    areas, they are inserted into a new feature class along with the
    source polygon attributes.

Comment: At the moment this is a link only answer and liable for deletion. Please provide some information to describe the link contents, and why you think it should work